# If I know the drain rate can we calculate the remainin time for battery?

Tags: python, data-science, battery

I know the draining rate.
I want to know after how many hours or minutes it will be totally drained

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overlow. This is a programming Q&A site, for specific programming questions (i.e. "I have this code, it should do that, but it does this instead"). Please take the time to look around for examples of proper questions for this site, and of course do visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think this doesn't belong to Stack Overflow!

---

But consider the following formula:

**Battery Life** = **Battery Capacity** [*mAh*] / **Load Current** [*mA*] * 0.70

The factor of *0.7* makes allowances for external factors which can affect battery life.

Example:

*5000 mAh* batttery with *250 mA* consumption leads to an estimate operation time of *14 hours*.

Answer (score 0):

Note the current battery life minus the time elapsed times the drain rate will equal 0 when there is no battery left.

In other words, the battery equals 0 when the time elapsed is equal to the current battery life divided by the drain rate.

If you don't know the current battery life to begin with, the best you can do is get some bounds by plugging in 100 and 0 for the current battery life.